# How to compare two jagged arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two jagged arrays containing information on some entities that I need to compare.

```
Dim MyArray1()
Dim MyArray2()

MyArray1(0) = Array("ID1", 2)
MyArray1(1) = Array("ID2", 7)
MyArray1(2) = Array("ID3", 5)
MyArray1(3) = Array("ID4", 3)

MyArray2(0) = Array("ID1", 5)
MyArray2(1) = Array("ID2", 8)
MyArray2(2) = Array("ID3", 6)
MyArray2(3) = Array("ID4", 9)
```

I'm looking for the best way of comparing these arrays, in this case I will need to get both the number difference between them. So ID1 = 3, ID2 = 1, etc. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use dictionaries rather than jagged arrays? You seem to be using jagged arrays as key-value maps, but they are not optimized for it.

Comment: Hi, the reason I didn't use dictionaries is that I was not familiar with them when I wrote my code. I did look it up now and it does seem like it might solve this issue, though I am also using the same arrays other places in my code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub compJaggedArrs()
Dim MyArray1(0 To 3)
Dim MyArray2(0 To 3)
Dim i As Long, j As Long

MyArray1(0) = Array("ID1", 2)
MyArray1(1) = Array("ID2", 7)
MyArray1(2) = Array("ID3", 5)
MyArray1(3) = Array("ID4", 3)

MyArray2(0) = Array("ID1", 5)
MyArray2(1) = Array("ID2", 8)
MyArray2(2) = Array("ID3", 6)
MyArray2(3) = Array("ID4", 9)

For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray2)
        If MyArray1(i)(0) = MyArray2(j)(0) Then
            Debug.Print MyArray1(i)(0) & " difference is: " & abs(MyArray1(i)(1) - MyArray2(j)(1))       
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Of course you can output the differences in another way. Just didn't know what you wanted to do with the results, it now prints to the debug window

Answer (score 3):

If both arrays will always have same size, then maybe would be easier to use dictionaries.

> **[Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)**

```
Sub COMPARING_VALUES()
Dim Dict1 As Object
Dim Dict2 As Object

Set Dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set Dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Dict1
    .Add "ID1", 2
    .Add "ID2", 7
    .Add "ID3", 5
    .Add "ID4", 3
End With

With Dict2
    .Add "ID1", 5
    .Add "ID2", 8
    .Add "ID3", 6
    .Add "ID4", 9
End With

Dim key As Variant
For Each key In Dict1.Keys
    Debug.Print Dict2(key) - Dict1(key)
Next key


End Sub
```

In this case, you can use Dictionaries because you are relating data with an ID (that means a key), not just their position in array, so probably it's easier to use dictionaries.

Executing this code will print in debugger these values:

```
 3 
 1 
 1 
 6
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Hi, it does indeed seem that I should have used dictionaries instead. Lesson learned, I will do more research into dictionaries through the link you provided and next time I come across an issue like this I will make sure to use them. Though as it is the end of this small project, I will simply use the loop posted. Thanks for enlightening me!